# Creating a Pandas DataFrame conditional on another DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two DataFrames. The first, `df1`, has historical time series data for a variety of tickers with a DateTime index that looks like this:

```
                       ABC              DEF            XYZ
 2011-06-06            10.00            10.00          10.0000   
 2011-06-17            10.00            10.00          10.0000   
 2011-06-21            10.00            10.00          10.0000   
 2011-06-22            10.00            10.00          10.0000   
 2011-06-23            10.00            10.00          10.0000   
 2011-06-24            10.00            10.00          10.0000   
 2011-06-30            10.00            10.00          10.0000   
 2011-07-11            10.00            10.00          10.0000
```

The second, `df2`, has three columns; a `Start_Date`, `End_Date`, and `Ticker`. Both the `Start_Date` and `End_Date` are in datetime format:

```
    End_Date Start_Date  Ticker
0 2011-06-27 2011-06-22  ABC
1 2011-06-30 2011-06-17  DEF
2 2011-06-25 2011-06-18  XYZ
```

I want to create a third DataFrame, `df3`, using the following code

```
df4 = df.copy()
df4.lock[:] = np.nan
```

Between `df2['Start_Date']` and `df2['End_Date']` I want to populate `df3` rows with `1.00` and leave the other rows as `np.nan`.

I've tried to create a function and also to iterate over `df2`.

```
def pos():
    position = 1
    for i in df2['Ticker']:
        df3.at[df2['Start_Date'], i] = position
    return pos
```

or

```
def pos():
    position = 1
    for index, row in df2.iterrows:
        df3.at[index, row['Start_Date']] = position
    return pos
```

The resulting `df3` would look like this:

```
                        ABC              DEF              XYZ
2011-06-06              NaN              NaN              NaN   
2011-06-17              NaN              1.0              NaN   
2011-06-21              NaN              1.0              1.0   
2011-06-22              1.0              1.0              1.0   
2011-06-23              1.0              1.0              1.0   
2011-06-24              1.0              1.0              1.0   
2011-06-30              NaN              1.0              NaN   
2011-07-11              NaN              NaN              NaN   
2011-07-13              NaN              NaN              NaN   
2011-07-14              NaN              NaN              NaN
```

I am not having much luck with either. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to apply a function to every row (or column) of a DataFrame, you can use df2.apply(your_function) See docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html In your case, you should be able to have your function check if the date falls between start and end, and if so, take the action you want. Apply returns a new DataFrame, so just call that new one df3

Comment: For clarity, please post what you think the final result should look like.

Comment: edited to include the final result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
d2 = df2.set_index('Ticker')
df3 = df1.copy()
for tick, col in df3.iteritems():
    d2 = df2.set_index('Ticker')
    sd = d2.at[tick, 'Start_Date']
    ed = d2.at[tick, 'End_Date']
    df3.loc[sd:ed, tick] = 1

df3

             ABC   DEF   XYZ
2011-06-06  10.0  10.0  10.0
2011-06-17  10.0   1.0  10.0
2011-06-21  10.0   1.0   1.0
2011-06-22   1.0   1.0   1.0
2011-06-23   1.0   1.0   1.0
2011-06-24   1.0   1.0   1.0
2011-06-30  10.0   1.0  10.0
2011-07-11  10.0  10.0  10.0
```